# Calculate the expected proportion of denied boardings

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

> An airline company knows that 20% of its passengers will not show up
>   for their scheduled flights. A plane has 80 seats. If the airline
>   company accepts 100 bookings, what is the expected proportion of
>   passengers to which the company will deny boarding?

This is what I thought:
The number of people who will show up is given by a binomial distribution: $S\sim Bin(100,0.8)$ which can be approximated by a normal distribution $S\sim N(80,16)$. The number of people who will not be able to fly is: $max(0,S-80)$. So the answer should be:
$\frac{E[max(0,S-80)]}{E[S]}$
Of course, $E[S]=80$.
How can I calculate $E[max(0,S-80)]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take the normal approximation to the binomial as is, half the time no passengers will be denied boarding and half the time we'll be looking at a value from the right [half of a normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).

[The exact calculation using normal approximation has been left out deliberately -- there should be something for you to still do, but if you do it correctly it comes out a little below 1.6]

Here's a simulation:

```
 mean(pmax(rbinom(100000, 100, 0.8)-80,0))
[1] 1.59157
```

Exact binomial calculation gives

```
  sum(dbinom(80:100,100,.8)*0:20)
 [1] 1.588803
```

whuber's comment about the continuity correction (which I mentioned earlier) is right -- I was misled by the visual appearance of the binomial near the peak to think it would help given we are calculating with a cut-off near the peak of the binomial, but it doesn't. It does tend to help - even in the tail - when the parameter is close to 1/2 but we're not in that situation, so more caution on my part (like double checking the correction would actually improve the approximation) was called for.

Comment: The Normal approximation would be fine for calculating probabilities of *symmetric* events in this situation, because the errors in the two arms of the distribution tend to cancel.  For this one-sided calculation, however, I worry a little about the size of the error.  In fact, *ignoring* the continuity correction actually gets you close to the correct proportion (I compute 0.01596 compared to the correct 0.01589) while introducing the continuity correction (of +0.00049) creates a relative error of more than 3%.

Comment: @whuber quite right. I've made some changes accordingly.